# How to exclude internal libraries from Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

These are the libraries that `twitter SDK` is using.

```
+--- com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.1.0
|    +--- com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:2.1.0
|    |    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.14
|    |    \--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2
|    |         \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0
|    |              \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0
```

Its using `okhttp3` library, and i need to exclude it, I have tried following, but this is not excluding the `okhttp3` library.

> ```
>  exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
> ```

I don't want to exclude parent libraries, just the child library.

Comment: Wouldn't excluding the library prevent the twitter SDK from working?

Comment: Yes, but okhttp3 is crashing 2 other libraries, so i need to exclude it, and i will try to add some other version, that may work will all of the libraries. But first i need to exclude it.

Comment: If you are looking to use a newer version of OkHttp, add your own `compile` statement for that version, and Gradle will usually substitute your newer version for the one that Twitter is seeking (at least for minor/patchlevel version changes).

Comment: @CommonsWare : but i want to try out an older version, and if i add other version and see `Gradle Tree`, it shows `->` symbol on conflicting libraries

Comment: Isn't there any possibility of excluding child libraries?

Comment: "but i want to try out an older version" -- I do not recommend that. Beyond that, please provide a [mcve], which would include the `build.gradle` file with your `exclude` statement, along with the output of the Gradle dependency report based on that `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to force specific version of a library:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy { 
        force 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:<<older version>>'
    }
}
```

or

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:<<older version>>' {
  force = true
}
```